# I'm streaming a basketball game and one computer, but I want to simutainiously share to another computer in the house

Tags: sharing

I'm streaming a basketball game on one computer, but I want to simultainiously share to another computer in the house. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of computer are you using?

Comment: Imac and mac mini running Yosemite, also ipads

Comment: It depends on your Internet connection type. If you have Ethernet on the master, then you can share it with others (via WiFi), if you have WiFi on the master then you can not share that.

Answer (score 1):

VNC connection is rather slow and without audio. I would recomment [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com) if You want to stream video and audio. It works really well especially on LAN. It uses video codecs and smart compression mechanisms to keep the stream fluid. Interface is not as good as native Apple app though.
It's free for private use.

Answer (score 0):

There are detailed guides at Apple's website. Here's [the one for Yosemite](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18688?locale=en_IL). You can download a free application called [Soundfly](http://abyssoft.com/software/soundfly/)<sup>1</sup> if you need audio.

<sup>**1** seems legit, download at your own risk.</sup>

Comment: Great (Thanks!) that works for video, but no audio. Any suggestions?

Comment: let me know if that does it